# Inner Join with an And Operator and Or Operator SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a query which has two operator condition, let say, i have 3 columns in table a and table now, i want to see result as if (a.id=b.id or a.cid=b.cid) And (a.site=b.site)

Table a

```
ID|CID|SITE
 1| 2 |sss
 2| 3 |ddd
 3| 4 |ddd
```

table b

```
ID|CID|SITE
 1| 2 |sss
 3| 3 |ddd
 3| 5 |sss
```

now the result should show,

```
ID|CID|SITE
 1| 2 |sss
 3| 3 |ddd
```

That means if (a.id=b.id AND a.site=b.site) OR (a.cid=b.cid AND a.sit=b.site)

Please help me out...

Comment: this is what i have tried, select a* from table1 as a inner join table2 as b on (a.id=b.id AND a.site=b.site) OR (a.cid=b.cid AND a.sit=b.site)

Answer (score 3):

Although you don't specify which table to take the results from, your sample output indicates that you want to take it from table b, so:

```
 Select * From tableb b 
 Where exists
    (Select * From tablea
     Where site = b.site
        And (id = b.id or 
             cid = b.cid))
```

Comment: Charles, this seems to be correct but i want a column from tablea along with the tableb results..

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
SELECT a.id,a.cid,a.site
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id=b.id AND a.site=b.site
UNION ALL
SELECT a.id,a.cid,a.site
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.cid=b.cid AND a.site=b.site
```

or maybe this?

```
SELECT a.id, a.cid, a.site
FROM a JOIN b on a.site=b.site
WHERE a.id=b.id OR a.cid=b.cid
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question, what do you mean by the following:

```
a.d=b.id or a.cid=b.cid
```

assuming by a.d you mean a.id then you are trying to join on the IDs of the two tables. I will rather explain the SQL inner join for you, then you can try to make use of it.

There are 3 types of joins in SQL server, inner, outer, and both (full). I think you need inner join.

Inner Join returns all the matching record in table B for each record in table A.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLEA ta INNER JOIN TABLEB tb on tb.ID = ta.ID
```

Make sure you understand that if there are duplicate records in either table, the join will return repeating records.